# supervisord not killing all spawned node processes on stop command

Tags: node.js, process, yarnpkg, supervisord

I encountered something weird when deploying a new service with supervisord. These are the relevant parts:

```
# supervisord.conf

[program:express]
command=yarn re-express-start
```

```
# package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "re-express-start": "node lib/js/client/Express.bs.js",
  }
}
```

When I run `supervisorctl start`, the node server is started as expected. But after I run `supervisorctl stop`, the server keeps on running even though supervisor thinks it's been killed.

If I change the `supervisord.conf` file to execute `node lib/js/client/Express.bs.js` directly (without going through `yarn`), then this works as expected. But I want to go through the `package.json`-defined script.

I looked into how the process tree looks like and but I don't quite understand *why*. Below are the processes before and after stopping the supervisord-managed service.

```
$ ps aux | grep node
user     12785  1.4  3.5 846404 72912 ?        Sl   16:30   0:00 node /usr/bin/yarn re-express-start
user     12796  0.0  0.0   4516   708 ?        S    16:30   0:00 /bin/sh -c node lib/js/client/Express.bs.js
user     12797  5.2  2.7 697648 56384 ?        Sl   16:30   0:00 /usr/bin/node lib/js/client/Express.bs.js
root     12830  0.0  0.0  14216  1004 pts/1    S+   16:30   0:00 grep --color=auto node

$ pstree -c -l -p -s 12785
systemd(1)───supervisord(7153)───node(12785)─┬─sh(12796)───node(12797)─┬─{node}(12798)
                                             │                         └─{node}(12807)
                                             ├─{node}(12786)
                                             └─{node}(12795)

$ supervisorctl stop express

$ ps aux | grep node
user     12797  0.7  2.7 697648 56384 ?        Sl   16:30   0:00 /usr/bin/node lib/js/client/Express.bs.js
root     12975  0.0  0.0  14216   980 pts/1    S+   16:32   0:00 grep --color=auto node

$ pstree -c -l -p -s 12797
systemd(1)───node(12797)─┬─{node}(12798)
                         └─{node}(12807)

$ kill 12797

$ ps aux | grep node
root     13426  0.0  0.0  14216   976 pts/1    S+   16:37   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

From the above, the "actual" workload process doing the server stuff has PID `12797`. It is spawned by the supervisor process and nested under a few more.
Stopping the supervisor process stops the processes with PIDs `12785` and `12796`, but *not* the `12797` which is actually reattached to the init process.

Any ideas on what is happening here? Is this due to *something* ignoring some SIGxxx signals? I assume it's the `yarn` invocation somehow eating those,
but I don't know how and how to reconfigure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well when I was running a node Express app. The problem seemed to be that I was having supervisor call `npm start` which refers to the `package.json` `start` script. That script simply calls `node app.js`. The solution seemed to be to directly call that command from the supervisor config file like so:

```
[program:node]
...
command=node app.js
...
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

In addition, I added `stopasgroup` and changed the `stopsignal` to QUIT. The stopsignal seemed to be required in order to properly kill the process.

I can now freely call `supervisorctl restart node:node_00` without having any `ERROR (spawn error)` errors.

Comment: Looks like the `stopasgroup=true` did the trick. Leaving the stopsignal as the default (TERM) works fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: Same here, `stopasgroup=true` did it.